# How to generate a link directing to all apps of a publisher in microsoft store?

Tags: uwp

I'm a uwp developer, and I have published 4 apps in Microsoft store.

Now I want to add a button, which can open the store page published by me.

Like below.

How? Thanks :)

[image]

Comment: simply search your developer username in store your all app apps will appear OR alternately create a one unique tag (e.g your user name) in all your apps in the store so whenever search your that username so all your apps will appear at once, i already done this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another schema available for WinStore for filtering by publisher

Here is example "ms-windows-store://publisher/?name=Printslon"

Launches a search for products from the specified publisher. Spaces in the name are allowed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-store-app

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to set unique tag in app store for your app which shows result for your app only or through your username as i mention in above comment

```
private async void YourButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-windows-store://search/?query=shubdragon"));
}
```

alternately you can also search for multiple tags (Not Recommended) -

```
"ms-windows-store://assoc/?Tags=Photos_Editor, Camera_App, FM_Radio_Tune, DevShare"
```

Insert your user name in query="YourUSerNameInTheStore" and it is case sensitive else it will give wrong result or something else.
Don't Forget the make scope async.

**Suggestion** you can use very weird tag like 2246jklm in all your apps then set it is as query=2246jklm so it will never show other apps result

Comment: Hi, Shubham. I used the code you pasted, the result shows all my apps, but also include some game apps, not my games. But still thank you, it helps : )

Comment: as i mention your tag should me unique else it will show other result also for e.g you can use your dev center username as tag so it will show your apps only, in my case i am using shubdragon so if i search in desktop this tag it show only my desktop apps and in mobile it show only my mobile apps

Comment: you can use very weird tag like 2246jklm in all your apps then set it is as query=2246jklm so it will never show other apps result
Many  website already do this , you can see many website launches windows app store with weird search query which show all its app

Comment: Thanks one more suggestion before setting tag search it in the store, 0.1% may be already use by other

Comment: A string like guid maybe needed, haha

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154674/discussion-between-shubham-sahu-and-vincent).